# AngularJS ng-grid - Row become unselected when we navigate between two pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I am facing an issue while using ng-grid. Following are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Select number of rows in 1st page, let say, you selected 2 rows. Then, "Selected Items" counts will show "2".
2. Now move to 2nd page and do not perform any action.
3. Now come back(navigate) to 1st page again.
4. Here, no row is selected but "Selected Items" counts still show "2". Moreover, if we select more rows, it will start incrementing the count from "2" to "3". And on unselecting, count will go back to "2" (but not to zero, in any case).

I also asked this issue in their github repo, but doesn't get any solution(till yet)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3224

Is there any way to fix this issue.

**NOTE**: I am already using ng-grid, so its impossible to me to switch to ui-grid.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not expected behaviour.  I'm not overly familiar with 2.x, but I think there is an api that lets you get the selected rows, and change the selected rows.  I'm not sure if there is an event that tells you the page has changed.

If there is, then you could listen for the page changed event, and then unselect the currently selected rows.